# How do i ensure I always get the new google games playerId instead of the legacy id?

Tags: android, google-play-games

While my app was in alpha and unpublished, anytime a user signed in to google play games i would get their id `Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mGoogleApiClient).getPlayerId()` and it would return an id in this format

> g07610263060548408114

Now that I am in an open beta however, using the same call gives me an id in this format

> 117053902313732480537

(I'm not saying that the progression from alpha to beta or that i published caused this, but it's when i started noticing a change.)

From reading a few issues in the unity plugin project on github, 
[Native Android Google+ User ID different than using Unity Plugin #1277](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/1277) and the issue it references, it seems that the second version of the id i'm now getting is an outdated version that is linked to the user's google plus account. The new version (with the prefixed g) is supposedly available so that the players don't need to have a google plus account in order to play my game. See [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html) post for the google announcement about the replacing of ids. It sounds like the unity plugin returns the new id while the native android libraries do not.

**So my question is, why in the newest version of google play games services (10.2.1) is the id that i get for my users the legacy id? And how can i get the new version-- the one that is the same as the participant ids in a match?**

I've tried using google's new sign in api's but that also gives me the legacy id. Even for users where before i was getting the new id format.

I could use this legacy id everywhere and it would at least be consistent, however the only id i get from 
turnBasedMatch.getParticipants.get(0).getPlayerId() is the new id, so i would never be able to map the two. I want to use the new id, but i can't get it anymore for new users.

My activity currently extends BaseGameActivity
 and this is some of the code i use to initialize the client before i tried the new sign in

`mPresenter = GameSetupPresenter.getInstance(getApiClient());
        getApiClient().registerConnectionCallbacks(mPresenter);
        getApiClient().registerConnectionFailedListener(mPresenter);`

`@Override
    public void onSignInSucceeded() {
        Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mPresenter.getGoogleApiClient()).getPlayerId();
    }`

This line where i get the playerId either returns the id in the legacy or the new format.

Using the new sign in process my code looks like this:

```
 GoogleSignInOptions options = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestId()
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestProfile()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.GAMES), new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE), new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
            .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.server_client_id), false)
            .build();

    mPresenter = GameSetupPresenter.getInstance(null);
    GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, mPresenter)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, options)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .build();

    mPresenter.bindGoogleApiClient(client);
    client.registerConnectionCallbacks(mPresenter);
    client.registerConnectionFailedListener(mPresenter);

    Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(client);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
if (request == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if(response == RESULT_OK) {
                Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(mPresenter.getGoogleApiClient()).getPlayerId();//returns different id's based on whether user was created before or after game was published.

                GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

                result.getSignInAccount().getId();//returns legacy id
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the samples in https://github.com/playgameservices/clientserverskeleton

One thing to be aware of is if you only use the games config and requestAuthCode(), there are no additional consent prompts for users.

The GoogleSignIn API does not use the games ID if you are requesting additional items and scopes.  To get the Games specific ID use:

```
GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

Log.d(TAG,"Legacy account = " + acct.getId());
Log.d(TAG,"Games Id:" + Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer
                (mGoogleApiClient).getPlayerId());
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
As i mentioned in my question
`Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer
                (mGoogleApiClient).getPlayerId())` doesn't always return the new id. In fact it always returns the legacy id for new signups. It will return the new id for users that signed up before i published (so it's at least consistent for them). But now that my game is published i only get legacy ids for new users. What can i do, so that that doesn't happen and so that i always get the new id?

Comment: please see my comment

Comment: let me look into a couple things and get back to you.

Comment: any progress on this?